# How can I execute only tests and ignore testsuites in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit4

I have a project that uses testsuites to call the tests within a project.

Running the tests with maven, it will correctly runs only the tests.

Running the tests with eclipse, it runs both the tests and the testsuites!

I could write a testsuite() to call all the testsuites in all the packages but **is there a way to only execute the tests in the project and not the testsuites?**

Partly this is to enable the clover plugin in eclipse to report the code coverage for the project

Answer (score 0):

This is expected in Eclipse.  To run tests, you must either give Eclipse a test class, a package, or a project.  It will run all tests and test suites in that selection.  I do not believe there is any way to do what you want.

I could only suggest refactoring so that your test suites are in a different project or package from your test cases.